# VB 6 Memory Limitation

Tags: vb6

A prospective client has a very large VB6 program. They claim that they are running into a memory limitation. They cannot add more lines of code.

Do you know what is the upper limit and is there are way around it?

Comment: @John Saunders you're really not helping. As usual.

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to amputate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's some documentation of VB's limits on MSDN:

[Code Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240819%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> The amount of code that can be loaded into a form, class, or standard
>   module is limited to 65,534 lines... [etc]

[Project Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716295%28VS.60%29.aspx):

> A single project can contain up to 32,000 "identifiers" (any
>   nonreserved keyword), which include, but are not limited to, forms,
>   controls, modules, variables, constants, procedures, functions, and
>   objects. Note that the actual number of identifiers is limited to
>   available memory.

[Data Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716182%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> The data segment (that is, the data defined in the Declarations
>   section) of the VBA module of any form or module in Visual Basic can
>   be up to 64K.

Comment: Good answer, but I cannot imagine actually hitting these limits.  To the OP, I would suggest breaking the project into several projects using ActiveX Dll projects.

Comment: @tcarvin... I actually hit the 32,000 identifiers limit several years ago (big swiss army knife style project). Solution (like your suggestion) was to split into multiple VB6 projects but sadly maintenance is now more complex and painful.